# Julia modulo of vector (or remainer of vector)

Tags: arrays, vector, julia, modulo, remainder

How do I obtain the modulo of a vector in Julia.

There are two ways in Julia to perform a modulo:

```
mod(9,5)
```

or equivalently:

```
9 % 5
```

However, neither works with a vector.

This also the came for computing the remainder of a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you use the element-wise modulus operator `.%`:

```
[34,456,3] .% 2
```

Which gives:

```
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 0
 1
```

**EDIT**: equivalently, you can use `mod.()`

Comment: ... or `mod.([34, 456, 3], 2)`

Comment: tnx, added an edit